# concurrentmodification exception -- setting an array element

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist, concurrentmodification

I read in JAVAdocs that concurrent modification exception comes when you structurally modify a list while iterating through it.In my case I am not changing the size of array but,just replacing some indices in the array. Tried out many things but this doesnt seem to work.

Providing a snippet below.(The code is a recursive function to solve n-queens problem)

```
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> solve(int a, String[] arr,int beg,
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result) {      
    for( int i=beg;i< a*a ;i++){
        String s = arr[i];
        if(s.equals(".")){
            //fill Q and look for valid combs
           arr[i] = "Q";
           if(i== (a*a)-1){
                 String[] t = (String[])(arr.clone());
                 result.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(t)));
           }else{
               ArrayList<Integer> filled = fillX(arr,i,a,"x");//this function fills "X" in queen's path and returns the filled indices

               ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tmp = solve(a,arr,i+1,result);
               if(!tmp.isEmpty()){
                    for(ArrayList<String> t :tmp){
                        result.add((ArrayList<String>)t.clone());
                     }
               }
                for(int x = 0;x< a*a;x++){                      
                    if(filled.contains(x)){
                        arr[x] = ".";//the exception goes away on removing this line
                    }                         
                }                 
           }
           arr[i] =".";
        }
    }
        return result;  
}
```

Stacktrace --

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
at Solution.solve(Solution.java:29)
at Solution.solveNQueens(Solution.java:7)
at Main.main(Main.java:323)
```

Comment: `arr[x)] = ".";` ... do you really have this in your code?  It obviously won't even compile.

Comment: Add your stacktrace, please

Comment: In what javadoc did you see a mention of *structurally* modifying a collection?  I don’t see that anywhere in the [ConcurrentModificationException javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).  In general, any modification followed by use of an Iterator created before the modification will throw ConcurrentModificationException, at least in collection classes which are not in the java.util.concurrent package.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the parentheses got added while some modifcation for here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you hit a typical Concurrent Modification scenario.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tmp = solve(a, arr, i + 1, result);
for (ArrayList<String> t : tmp) { // <-- iterating through the result of a recursive call.
    result.add((ArrayList<String>)t.clone());
}
...
return result; // <-- while the recursive call returns the `result` argument.
```

It is basically doing something like:

```
for (ArrayList<String> t : result) {
    result.add((ArrayList<String>)t.clone());
}
```

IMHO, you either can make `resolve` a `void` method, and add results directly to the passed in result argument; or you can remove the result parameter and make each recursive call create a local List and return it.

Comment: Thanks ! The exception went away after your suggestion.But I am still not clear why in my code when I was removing this line the exception was going away and coming back on adding it.

Comment: for(int x = 0;x< a*a;x++){                      
                    if(filled.contains(x)){
                        arr[x] = ".";//the exception goes away on removing this line
                    }                         
                }